# Getting error 'Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, undefined

Here is a look at my code. Any time I click on one of the cards, I get the error in my console:

> Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined

Why is this happening?

```
var cards = [
{
    "rank": "queen",
    "suit":"hearts",
    "cardImage": "images/queen-of-hearts.png"
},{
    "rank": "queen",
    "suit":"diamonds",
    "cardImage": "images/queen-of-diamonds.png"
},{
    "rank": "king",
    "suit":"hearts",
    "cardImage": "images/king-of-hearts.png"
},{
    "rank": "king",
    "suit":"diamonds",
    "cardImage": "images/king-of-diamonds.png"
}

]

var cardsInPlay = [];

var checkForMatch = function() {
    this.setAttribute('src', this.cardImage);
    if(cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
        cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]?alert('You found a match!'):alert('Sorry, try again.');
    }
}

var flipCard = () => {
    var cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log(`User flipped ${cards[cardId].rank}`);
    cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
    console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
    console.log(cards[cardId].suit);

    checkForMatch();
}

var createBoard = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i ++) {
        var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
        cardElement.setAttribute('src','images/back.png');
        cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i);
        cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
        document.getElementById('game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
    }

}

createBoard();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`this` in you're context is referring to the function `checkForMatch()`, not `flipCard()`, meaning if you were to use `this` in `flipCard()`, it will work because it is referring to `cardElement`. `this` inside `checkForMatch()` is referring to the function, **not**, `cardElement`.

What you could do is to replace `this.setAttribute('src', this.cardImage);`, to what ever `this` was suppose to be.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will make that change. I am still getting the same error in the first line of my flipCard().

Comment: Its what Kermit said, arrow functions point to the parent, so Its selecting `game-board`. Change `this` to  `cardElement`

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use arrow-function because of in arrow-function,`this` is point to parent scope.so `this` is `undefined`. you should be cautious when using arrow-function.

Comment: thanks. i will read up on arrow-fuctions for a better understanding